# More elegant way to wait for a boolean to be 'true'

Tags: swift, while-loop, boolean

I am a beginner in Swift, so this is how I wait for a boolean variable to be true:

```
while (boolVar == false) {}
```

I know that eventually, from another method, this variable will be set to true. Is there a better way to achieve the above? I'm not sure if that is the most elegant and/or efficient way.

Comment: Use a `Semaphore`, [for example](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb), [example](https://medium.com/@roykronenfeld/semaphores-in-swift-e296ea80f860), [example](https://medium.com/@derrickho_28266/semaphores-in-swift-1f5800f90945) - or use a closure style call back

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context in your question in order to get relevant help.

Comment: You want to "wait" for it to be true? Or "trigger" something when it becomes true ?

Comment: @Olympiloutre Basically, I have some code I want to execute after the variable becomes true.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Xcoder Updated comment ;)

Comment: you can look at a `didSet` method. This is set within the variable definition, and will trigger a code when the value is changed. You just have to check its value and trigger the function accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple swifty way is to use `didSet`

```
var boolVar:Bool = false {
    didSet {
       if boolVar {
          // do job
       } 
    } 
}
```